# Unable to retrieve Private Key from KeyStore

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key, android-keystore

I am trying to make an Chat app which uses RSA algorithm for encryption. After But when I try to decrypt messages I am getting this error below.

Here is how I am creating keys;

```
  if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 25);
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setAlias(alias)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
                KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
                generator.initialize(spec);

            }
```

And here is how I tryed to decrypt messages;

Definition the KeyStore;

```
 static KeyStore keyStore;
```

Loading keyStore in onCreate method:

```
  try{
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
    } 
    catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Decrypt Function:

```
      public String decryptString(String alias, String decrypted) {
    try {

        KeyStore.Entry entry;
        //ERROR HAPPENS HERE.
        entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry;

        Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());


        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(decrypted, Base64.DEFAULT)), output);
        ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
        int nextByte;
        while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            values.add((byte) nextByte);
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = values.get(i);
        }

        String finalText = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");
        return finalText;

    } catch (IOException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchPaddingException | UnrecoverableEntryException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

I am getting this error below;

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.furkan.profil, PID: 10591
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.KeyStore$Entry java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(java.lang.String, java.security.KeyStore$ProtectionParameter)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.furkan.profil.RSAHelper.decryptString(RSAHelper.java:180)
                                                                   at com.furkan.profil.Chat.ChatActivity$4.onChildAdded(ChatActivity.java:251)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: OK, so you've changed it. You are however shuffling the exception creating the key store under the table (empty catch block, use `IllegalStateException` instead), you haven't indicated the line where the exception occurs and finally your exception seems at odds with your code.

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong with that last one, you probably need to create and set a [(password) call back handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html).

Comment: I've added some other catch clause which Android Studio offered me and also edited where exception occurs. I am still getting same error. 

Why do you want me to use call back handlers? Can you please explain to me?

Comment: Because of the line `android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)` in your stacktrace. I presume that the `printStackTrace()` doesn't print anything (I'd avoid `printStackTrace`, just use `throw new IllegalStateException("KeyStore could not be initialized", e)` as it will not keep running when you get an error and for the compiler it counts as an exit point) - and in the end it will still print the stacktrace of course.

Comment: Instead of a throw I've changed all of the catch clauses and reshaped question. But I am still getting same error. I've double checked my alias but it is OK.

Comment: Have you by now implemented a handler and checked if it gets called?

Comment: ` handle = new Handler();

            runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
                    }  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
                        handle.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handle.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

                }
            };
            runnable.run();`

Comment: I am not so familiar with handlers. I've tried something but still getting the same error.

Comment: I've found solution. I answered below. Thanks for your helps @MaartenBodewes

Comment: OK, well, glad you found it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just noticed that I am accessing this method from another activity and this I am not triggering onCreate() method when I try to access method. I added;

```
try{
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("KeyStore could not be initialized", e);
        }
```

lines to decryptString() method. After that my problems are solved.